# In Google Earth Engine, can I export a layer with visual parameters added to a GeoTIFF?

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine

I am trying to get a LandSAT-8 image of the certain region with cloud cover 2. I am using some visual parameters and adding my layer. I want to export this layer to GeoTIFF but at the moment I am exporting the image which is without the visualization parameters I have chosen. So is it possible to export the visual layer instead of the image? Following is my code:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 25))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 31))
.filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER', 2));
var image = ee.Image(collection.sort('CLOUD_COVER', false).first()).select(['B2']);
var visParams = {
  bands: ['B2'],
  min: 400,
  max: 1500,
  gamma: [1.5]
};
Map.addLayer(image, visParams, 'MyImage');
Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image,
    description: '25_31_B2',
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour] which emphasizes the importance of asking one question per Question. Please [Edit] the question to focus on your primary issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can created a 3-band RGB image for export using [ee.Image.visualize()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagevisualize) and the same visualization parameters you used for displaying the interactive map layer, using this syntax:

```js
Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image.visualize(visParams),
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! This does work but the GeoTIFF image generated is of a low resolution. How do I increase the resolution such that 1 px corresponds to 30 meters?

Comment: Include the scale parameter, same as you did in the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Define pixel size while exporting e.g.

```
Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image.visualize(visParams),
    scale: 30,
    ...
});
```